# Brasero burn error

Tags: brasero, burning

I get an error when burning with brasero on a blank DVD.
what would be the problem? ..

This the link to the error report:
http://ubuntuone.com/2ekL3hVV10vPs0MZkVsOEr

```
BraseroLibburn SCSI error condition on command 2Ah WRITE(10): [3 0C 82] Write error
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn Libburn reported an error SCSI error on write(536544,16): [3 0C 82] Write error
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_error
BraseroLibburn finished with an error
BraseroLibburn asked to stop because of an error
    error       = 1
    message = "SCSI error on write(536544,16): [3 0C 82] Write error"
BraseroLibburn stopping
Session error : SCSI error on write(536544,16): [3 0C 82] Write error (brasero_burn_record brasero-burn.c:2856)
```

Comment: What kind of drive and media are you using?

Comment: I was using a seagate cddvdw sh-s223c. And I was burning Ubuntu 12.04LTS 64Bit

Answer (score 0):

Probably a cdrkit / wodim / genisoimage problem. Those types of problems have occurred for years since they replaced cdrtools / cdrecord / mkisofs with it.